# Cancelling Dropbox getFile download

Tags: android, dropbox-api

When using the Android Dropbox SDK, does anyone know of the best way to cancel a download after the getFile call starts. At the moment, my AsyncTask class does the following:

```
@Override
protected O2ShellFileManagerError doInBackground(File... params) {
    if (params[0] == null) {
        return new O2ShellFileManagerError(
                "No File found.",
                O2ShellErrorCode._o2sfm_ec_unknown);
    }

    File mFile = params[0];

    try {
        DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi = O2DropboxStorage
                .getDropboxSession(mContext);

        // mOutputStream is class level field.
        mOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
        DropboxFileInfo info = mDBApi.getFile(mDropboxPath, null,
                mOutputStream, new ProgressListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(long bytes, long total) {
                        if (!isCancelled())
                            publishProgress(bytes, total);
                        else {
                            if (mOutputStream != null) {
                                try {
                                    mOutputStream.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    } catch (DropboxException e) {
        Log.e("DbExampleLog",
                "Something went wrong while getting file.");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("DbExampleLog", "File not found.");

    } finally {
        if (mOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                mOutputStream.close();
                mOutputStream = null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    /*
     * The task succeeded
     */
    return null;
}
```

So my workaround above essentially closes the mOutputStream in the OnProgess method which generates the DropboxException. Is there a better / cleaner way than this?

Comment: It was about a year ago when I was looking for a solution. I'm afraid I didn't find a cleaner solution then to what I used in the code above. Not sure if the API has changed since or if Dropbox has recommended an approach. So essentially I cancel the AsyncTask and look for the isCancelled() flag in the OnProgress method. You can either set another class level boolean flag in that method or set mOutputStream to null and check for null in the DropboxException catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the getFileStream API to get DropboxInputStream.

```
public DropboxAPI.DropboxInputStream getFileStream(java.lang.String path, java.lang.String rev)
```

When a user cancels the download, call the close function of DropboxInputStream.

I think this method can release the resources totally.